# Wget trying to write to original request?

Tags: shell, hash, terminal, wget

I use wget for simple things so don't scream if there is an obvious answer to my problem but here is an example of a wget for a simple image:

```
MBP:bin Mike$ wget http://www.mactricksandtips.com/wp-content/uploads/main_page_images/terminal-small.png
--2011-04-25 12:48:05--  http://www.mactricksandtips.com/wp-content/uploads/main_page_images/terminal-small.png
Resolving www.mactricksandtips.com... 209.20.76.249
Connecting to www.mactricksandtips.com|209.20.76.249|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 4432 (4.3K) [image/png]
terminal-small.png: Permission denied

Cannot write to `terminal-small.png' (Permission denied).
MBP:bin Mike$
```

Any suggestions on why its not simply writing it to my computer? This happens for every single wget request I make...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file exists already on your machine, check its permissions. You may not have the writes to overwrite it. As well, check the permissions on the containing directory to see if you're even allowed to write in there.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to have write permissions to that folder. I'm not sure what distro you use, but prepending `sudo` might do the trick:

```
sudo wget http://www.mactricksandtips.com/wp-content/uploads/main_page_images/terminal-small.png
```

Comment: That's like nuking a building to get a bedbug in one of the closets. Running wget as root, even if it is via sudo, is not a good idea.

Comment: Nice example ;) I don't usually do this, but I wasn't really opt to telling the OP to `chmod` and `chown` files and directories...